# PHP - How can I write this IF and ELSE statement cleaner and faster

Tags: php, arrays, cdn, fopen

This code I wrote along time ago. It checks an external server for an image, if it exists, it will echo the image within a list. I have it up to 13 records to check. I thought an array would be best here but not sure how they work.

```
    $a1="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/1/medium.jpg";
              $a2="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/2/medium.jpg";
              $a3="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/3/medium.jpg";
              $a4="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/4/medium.jpg";
              $a5="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/5/medium.jpg";
              $a6="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/6/medium.jpg";
              $a7="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/7/medium.jpg";
              $a8="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/8/medium.jpg";
              $a9="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/9/medium.jpg";
              $a10="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/10/medium.jpg";
              $a11="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/11/medium.jpg";
              $a12="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/12/medium.jpg";
              $a13="".$cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/13/medium.jpg";
              if(@fopen($a1,"r")){
                  echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$a1.'" alt="" /></li>';
            }
if(@fopen($a2,"r")){echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$a2.'" alt="" /></li>';
}
if(@fopen($a3,"r")){echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$a3.'" alt="" /></li>';
}
if(@fopen($a4,"r")){echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$a4.'" alt="" /></li>';
}
if(@fopen($a5,"r")){echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$a5.'" alt="" /></li>';
}
if(@fopen($a6,"r")){echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$a6.'" alt="" /></li>';
}
if(@fopen($a7,"r")){echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$a7.'" alt="" /></li>';
}
if(@fopen($a8,"r")){echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$a8.'" alt="" /></li>';
}
if(@fopen($a9,"r")){echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$a9.'" alt="" /></li>';
}
if(@fopen($a10,"r")){echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$a10.'" alt="" /></li>';
}
if(@fopen($a11,"r")){echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$a11.'" alt="" /></li>';
}
if(@fopen($a12,"r")){echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$a12.'" alt="" /></li>';
}
```

Comment: have you heard about loops?

Comment: ...or [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)?

Comment: Hey, are you really thinks that the reordering this code will make it faster?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 14; $i++)
{
   $elem = $cdnurl . "assets/" . $pid . "/$i/medium.jpg";
   if(is_readable($elem))
   {
      echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$elem.'" alt="" /></li>';
   }
}
```

Comment: although, for testing the existence of a file there is a function that tests this existence file_exists(). No need to try to open the file...

Comment: Agreed, is_readable ALSO checks if the file exists at all. So it's a double-check, which makes it more suitable than file_exists.

Comment: @symcbean as far as i know... file_exists tests the existence of the file. True that the file can exist and not be readable by the server software, then, when your browser call the file you get an error. But, is_readable give your the readibility of the image for the user that runs php, and depending of php (cgi, apache module, ...) is not necesarily true that the image readable by php is readable by apache...

Answer (score 2):

Using a foreach-loop does not make it faster, but will make it look cleaner.

Your design is wrong, you shouldn't have a need to check for the existence of the assets each time the page loads. Make the script generate the HTML and load that HTML instead of connecting to the CDN each time.

You're putting twice as much load on the CDN now. If you need to hide certain `<li>` elements if the image is missing, use Javascript to remove the element if the image fails to load.

A code that assumes an URL like "... number ...":

```
<?php
foreach (range(0, 13) as $number) {
    $url = $cdnurl . "assets/$pid/$number/medium.jpg";
    echo '<li class="royalSlide">
        <img src="' . $url . '" onerror="parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(parentNode)" alt="" />
    </li>';
}
?>
```

This code is an enhancement of the code from your question:

```
<?php
foreach (range(0, 13) as $number) {
    $url = $cdnurl . "assets/$pid/$number/medium.jpg";
    // skip URLs which cannot be found
    if (!file_exists($url)) continue;

    echo '<li class="royalSlide">
        <img src="' . $url . '" alt="" />
    </li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: This does not make sense. What solution are you suggesting?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid I assumed that the code in your question is loaded each time a new request is performed without any kind of caching. The suggestion: generate the HTML to be included once and put that in ech page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a list.

A good idea would be to create it with a for :

```
$a = array();
for($i = 0; î < 14; ++$i)
{
    $a[] = $cdnurl."assets/".$pid."/".$i."/medium.jpg";
}
```

Then you can read it :

```
foreach($a as $tmpA) 
{
...
}
```

Inside this you have to test if this is an image you have on your server, and display it.
But you shouldn't use fopen. For a lot of resae.

At first you use @ because you d'ont want to have any Wrning on this, if you have warning that's you are doing wring, and php is trying to change that for you. Taht's your work to have clean code.
But more important, fopen create a ressource based on the file open. Then in this page you create 14 ressources ! And they will be destroy at the end of the page becouse you never close it.

There is a php function which is : file_exitsts. Taht's the right one for you :

```
foreach($a as $tmpA) 
{
    if (file_exists($filename)) 
    {
        echo '<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$tmpA.'" alt="" /></li>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can make this code cleaner, you cannot make it faster. 
Checking images from the outside servers is a terrible idea by itself and it ALWAYS be slow. Just because it's **external** server.

I am wondering if there is any reason to check for every image existence. Are they so fast in change?

Answer (score -1):

```
for($i=1;i<=13;i++){
  $item =$cdnurl.'assets/'.$pid.'/'.$i.'/'.medium.jpg;
  echo (@fopen($item,'r')?'<li class="royalSlide"><img src="'.$item.'" alt="" /></li>':'');
}
```

would do the trick assuming that the files are indeed named by number